# MS Access QUERY: Date Parameter criteria on calculated date field

Tags: ms-access

I have a query that attaches dates to records, and I want the query to only return records whose newly attached dates are within the range of my input parameters.

In the Criteria block:

Between [StartDate] And [EndDate] does not work.

while...

Between #6/1/17# And #10/1/17# does work.

I assume it has to be a formatting issue, but don't know where to go from here.  How can I marry the two (my calculated date and the input date parameters) fields so they compare correctly?

The SQL follows, I've copied the http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html sample database with plans to tweak it as needed.

```
PARAMETERS StartDate DateTime, EndDate DateTime;
SELECT qryCoreEventCartesian.EventID, qryCoreEventCartesian.InstanceID, DateAdd([qryCoreEventCartesian]![PeriodTypeID],[qryCoreEventCartesian]![InstanceID]*[qryCoreEventCartesian]![PeriodFreq],[qryCoreEventCartesian]![BeginDate]) AS EventDate, qryCoreEventCartesian.PID, qryCoreEventCartesian.Type, qryCoreEventCartesian.Comments, qryCoreEventCartesian.BeginDate, qryCoreEventCartesian.RecurCount, qryCoreEventCartesian.PeriodFreq, qryCoreEventCartesian.PeriodTypeID
FROM ltPeriodType INNER JOIN qryCoreEventCartesian ON ltPeriodType.PeriodTypeID = qryCoreEventCartesian.PeriodTypeID
WHERE (((DateAdd([qryCoreEventCartesian]![PeriodTypeID],[qryCoreEventCartesian]![InstanceID]*[qryCoreEventCartesian]![PeriodFreq],[qryCoreEventCartesian]![BeginDate])) Between [StartDate] And [EndDate]))
ORDER BY DateAdd([qryCoreEventCartesian]![PeriodTypeID],[qryCoreEventCartesian]![InstanceID]*[qryCoreEventCartesian]![PeriodFreq],[qryCoreEventCartesian]![BeginDate]);
```

Comment: 'does not work' means what - error message, wrong results, nothing happens? Those dynamic input parameters work for me. However, I NEVER use dynamic parameterized queries. I prefer VBA, review: http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: What is the expression for the calculated field?

Comment: Are `[StartDate]` and `[EndDate]` actual field names? If not, replace them with your field names.

Comment: Being too concise is not helpful.  You need to share the full SQL statement, so the relevant contexts are all visible.  How else could we know the details of whether you declared [StartDate] and [EndDate] properly or at all, how you related your "calculated date" to the condition you show.  I assume by "criteria block" you mean in the SQL WHERE clause? Or are you trying to insert the condition in an Access filter property?

Comment: Although Access will automatically create parameters out of unknown symbols, dates are particularly fussy.  When prompting for Variant (the default) parameter values, it will not properly recognize input as dates.  You must formally declare your parameters, which is always a good habit anyway.  You can do this in the query design mode, but the SQL will look like:  `PARAMETERS StartDate DateTime, EndDate DateTime;
SELECT  ...`

Comment: C Perkins had the answer.  I had checked the parameters section earlier today, and must have overlooked the Date with Time data type.  Worked like a charm!